# Быстрый алгоритм генерации ключей в схеме Шнорра

Tags: python-3.x, криптография, цифровая-подпись

Дано: тест на простоту, функция генерации простого числа.

Нужно найти такой алгоритм, который генерирует простое число-часть открытого ключа `q` такое, что:

`(p - 1) % q = 0`, где

`p` - простое число 1024 бит и также генерируемая часть ключа,

`q` - 160 бит.

Тест Миллера-Рабина:

```
def milrab(n, k):
    if n < 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return 0
    d = n - 1
    r = 0
    while d % 2 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        r += 1
    for i in range(k):
        a = random.randint(2, n - 2)
        x = pow(a, d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
            continue
        for j in range(r - 1):
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
            if x == n - 1:
                continue
        return False  # составное
    return True  # простое
```

Генерация простого числа размером `bits` битов:

```
def pgen(bits):
    prime = False
    a = 0
    while not prime:
        a = random.randint(2**(bits - 1), 2**bits - 1)
        prime = milrab(a, 7)
    return a
```

Части открытого ключа `p` и `q`:

```
def gen_p():
    return pgen(1024)

def gen_q(p):
    q = pgen(160)
    while (p - 1) % q != 0:
        q = pgen(160)
    return q
```

Проблема в том, что генерация `q` идет очень медленно. Есть быстрый способ посчитать `q` как множитель `p - 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что я пришел к тому, что можно генерировать простое число `q` (160 бит), затем генерировать еще одно число, назовем `q_p`, четное и длиной 1024-160=864 бит, которое мы умножаем на `q` и прибавляем единицу (если длина произведения получилась 1023 бита, переходим на следующую итерацию и заново генерируем `q_p`), таким образом получая `p`, простоту которого проверяем тестом.

Кроме того в тесте при генерации случайного числа (в моем случае оно называется `a`) я поставил диапазон 2:200 (вместо 2:n-2) для n > 202.

Время выполнения снизилось до 0-5 секунд.